# Excel addins for office 2013

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

We have on hand some custom-made Excel add-ins that were designed to work with Excel 2003.  We would like to upgrade to Office 2013, but the add-ins do not function properly in the new version.  Is it possible to convert these add-ins to work with Office 2013? If so, what is the best way convert them?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic. I suggest you contact the people who made the add-ins.

Comment: @CharlieRB Sorry but the original programmer is no longer an option.

Comment: Do you have the source code? Are you a programmer (or do you have any programmers working for your company), or can you hire a programmer? Try to diagnose the problem more finely than "the add-ins do not function properly", and try to fix it. If you get stuck on something specific, then come back and ask about that.  Although, at that point, your question may belong on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no utility to convert VBA code from one Office vintage to another.  The object model has changed in numerous, small ways as each new version has come out; an impressive effort was made to retain forward compatibility, but problems have still been inevitable (I've encountered them myself).  I have to imagine it would be too difficult to make a universal conversion tool that would be guaranteed to retain the functionality of old code.

So, I'm afraid you're facing a debugging/re-coding campaign to get your custom add-ins working again for Excel 2013.  My preferred resource for this sort of thing is MSDN; when the code throws an error, search for the problematic object/function on Google with, say, `Excel Range.FillDown site:msdn.microsoft.com`.  It will hopefully provide sufficient information to get the code working again, as long as you have someone with a reasonable programming background to interpret it.

If you don't have a suitable software developer on hand, you might try a freelance contracting service such as [eLance](http://www.elance.com).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps time to look for a VBA expert.

Answer (score 0):

Is your office 2013 64-bit? If so, source of the problem may not be Office 2013 itself. 64bit and 32bit macros are not competible. You can try to install 32bit version.